# Show all the records in one table and only matching records in second, why is left outer join not working?

Tags: sql-server, join

We have two tables, Directors and Employee

Directors table contains all records for a particular Director.

In some instances, a director can be in charge of one or more departments.

The query below shows example of a director being responsible for three departments:

```
select deptnum, DeptName, Empname, DirectorId from Directors where DirectorId ='9884476'


DeptNum         DeptName    EmpName         DirectorID  
750              HR          Doe, Jane      9884476 
755          Administration  Doe, Jane      9884476 
803        Veterans Affairs  Doe, Jane      9884476
```

A director is also an employee in Employee table as shown by sample data below:

```
 DeptNum    Department  Empname        Empnum   Email                    Zip
   750          HR     Doe, Jane       9884476  Jane.doe@yahoo.com     70612
```

What I am trying to do is run a query that displays the Director information along with the three departments she is responsible for but the query below only produces just one record, HR as shown below:

```
DirectorID  DeptNum Department  EmpName EmpNum           Email              Zip
9884476      750    HR           Doe, Jane    9884476   Jane.doe@yahoo.com  70612
9884476      750    HR           Doe, Jane    9884476   Jane.doe@yahoo.com  70612
9884476      750    HR           Doe, Jane    9884476   Jane.doe@yahoo.com  70612
```

Any ideas what's off with the query below?

```
select h.DirectorID,
       e.DeptNum, 
       e.Department,
       e.EmpName as EmployeeName,
       e.empnum,  
       e.Email,
       e.zip
FROM Employee e  
LEFT OUTER JOIN Directors h on e.empnum = h.directorId  
                   AND h.directorid = '9884476'
WHERE e.Password = 'T400s'
```

I have also tried LEFT JOIN but to no avail.

Your assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try `h.Department` rather than `e.Department`. Also, `OUTER` is an optional keyword - so `LEFT JOIN` and `LEFT OUTER JOIN` are exactly the same thing. No need to try "both".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want h.DeptNum and h.DeptName from Directors rather than those of e table.

Comment: That's it!

Thank you very much